# python. TypeError: Car() takes no arguments

Tags: python

Пишу класс.  высвечивается ошибка

```
my_new_car = Car('audi', 'a4', 2016)
TypeError: Car() takes no arguments
```

Вроде все правильно . не вижу что не так.

```
class Car():
    def _init_(self, make, model, year):
         self.make = make
         self.model = model
         self.name = year
    def get_decribed_name(self):
        long_name = str(self.year) + ' ' + self.make + ' ' + self.model
        return long_name.title()
my_new_car = Car('audi', 'a4', 2016)
print(my_new_car.get_decribed_name())
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код, ошибки и текст раздельно и добавьте метку [tag:python]

Comment: `__init__`, а не `_init_`

Answer (score 3):

Исправьте вот так:

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
         self.make = make
         self.model = model
         self.year = year
    def get_decribed_name(self):
        long_name = str(self.year) + ' ' + self.make + ' ' + self.model
        return long_name.title()

my_new_car = Car('audi', 'a4', 2016)
print(my_new_car.get_decribed_name())
```