# Python:В 13 строчке выдает ошибку помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python

```
class capybara:
    def _init_(self, name, age, color):

        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.color = color

    def eat_mandarins (sеlf):
        return f"{self.name} is eat_mandarins."

    def swim(self):
        return f"{self.name} is swimming in the water."
    
    def sleep(self):
        return f"{self.name} is sleeping."12

#Создание экземпляра класса

my_capybara = capybara ("Моня", 2, "белый")

#Вывод информации в консоль

print(f"Name: {my_capybara.name}")

print(f"Age: {my_capybara.age} years")

print(f"Color: my_capybara.color}")

print(my_capybara.eat_mandarins())

print(my_capybara.swim())

print(my_capybara.sleep())
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Уже была такая проблема: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1166318

Answer (score 5):

`__init__` (конструктор) пишется с двумя нижними подчеркиваниями. Рабочий код

```
class capybara:
    def __init__(self, name, age, color):

        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.color = color

    def eat_mandarins (sеlf):
        return f"{sеlf.name} is eat_mandarins."
    def swim(self):
        return f"{self.name} is swimming in the water."
    def sleep(self):
        return f"{self.name} is sleeping."

#Создание экземпляра класса

my_capybara = capybara("Моня", 2, "белый")

#Вывод информации в консоль

print(f"Name: {my_capybara.name}")

print(f"Age: {my_capybara.age} years")

print(f"Color: {my_capybara.color}")

print(my_capybara.eat_mandarins())

print(my_capybara.swim())

print(my_capybara.sleep())
```

Comment: [*...этот символ иногда называют «Нижнее подчёркивание», что недопустимо по правилам русского языка и является плеоназмом — подчёркивание всегда выполняется снизу.*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)